# How do I get rid of Boolean method is always inverted warning?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

```kotlin
fun findError(puzzle: Array<IntArray>): Boolean {
    for (z in 0..8) {
        val blockNums = mutableListOf<Int>()
        val xNums = mutableListOf<Int>()
        val yNums = mutableListOf<Int>()

        for (index in 0..8) {
            xNums.add(puzzle[z][index])
            yNums.add(puzzle[index][z])
            blockNums.add(puzzle[blocks.xy[z + 1][index]][blocks.xy[z][index]])
            if (blockNums.count() != blockNums.toSet().count() ||
                yNums.count() != yNums.toSet().count() ||
                xNums.count() != xNums.toSet().count()) return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

This function works as desired but the Intellij IDE gives this warning. "Boolean method 'findError' is always inverted". I kind of understand what it means and I know I could suppress it.

I can't figure out how to rewrite the code block to satisfy the error and not change the functionality. Should I just suppress it or is there a more proper way to express this? I'm a beginner that is learning.

```kotlin
public final data class Blocks public constructor(blockNums: kotlin.collections.MutableList<kotlin.Int>, blockNumsFinal: kotlin.collections.MutableSet<kotlin.Int>, xy: kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.Int>>) {
    public final val blockNums: kotlin.collections.MutableList<kotlin.Int> /* compiled code */

    public final val blockNumsFinal: kotlin.collections.MutableSet<kotlin.Int> /* compiled code */

    public final var xy: kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.Int>> /* compiled code */

    public final operator fun component1(): kotlin.collections.MutableList<kotlin.Int> { /* compiled code */ }

    public final operator fun component2(): kotlin.collections.MutableSet<kotlin.Int> { /* compiled code */ }

    public final operator fun component3(): kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.Int>> { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

I found a way to rewrite the function not using the '!' symbol. This should satisfy the intention of the warning to use positives instead of negatives. It still gives the warning. I think Bas Leijdekkers comment about the inspection may be correct.

```
fun findError(puzzle: Array<IntArray>): Boolean {
    val blockNums = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val xNums = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val yNums = mutableListOf<Int>()
    var counts = 0
    for (z in 0..8) {
        blockNums.clear()
        xNums.clear()
        yNums.clear()

        for (index in 0..8) {
            xNums.add(puzzle[z][index])
            yNums.add(puzzle[index][z])
            blockNums.add(puzzle[blocks.xy[z + 1][index]][blocks.xy[z][index]])
            if (blockNums.count() == blockNums.toSet().count() &&
                yNums.count() == yNums.toSet().count() &&
                xNums.count() == xNums.toSet().count()) {
                counts++
            }
        }

    }
    return counts == 81
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add the warning message...

Comment: Does the IDE offer you an [Invert method](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/09/the-inspection-connection-issue-2/) option to auto-fix this?

Comment: It only gives the option to suppress.

Comment: Where do you use this function? Do you use it only once or only with the same parameter? Sometimes IntelliJ gives a warning if you will always receive the same outcome from a function.

Comment: I think the problem is that it's a loop with nine iterations. If any one fails the puzzle isn't solved. If they all pass it falls through and true is returned. I believe the intention of the warning is to not use '!' and act on a positive expression. Not sure how to make this positive.

Comment: The inspection is not working correctly on Kotlin code: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-306891/Strange-inspection-result-about-boolean-method-always-inverted

Comment: @Bas Leijdekkers I believe you may be correct. I found a way to rewrite the code using positives and still gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Which line is the IntelliJ warning you about, is it this statement?

```
if (blockNums.count() != blockNums.toSet().count() ||
                yNums.count() != yNums.toSet().count() ||
                xNums.count() != xNums.toSet().count()) return false
```

if so, it is because this is complex and likely difficult for someone other than you to understand.  Here's two ideas about how you might make reduce the complexity:
(1)

```
if (blockNums.size != blockNums.toSet().size) return false
if (yNums.size != yNums.toSet().size) return false
if (xNums.size != xNums.toSet().size) return false
```

or (2)

```
val blocksDiffer = (blockNums.size != blockNums.toSet().size)
val yDiffer = (yNums.size != yNums.toSet().size)
val xDiffer = (xNums.size != xNums.toSet().size)
if(blocksDiffer || yDiffer || xDiffer) return false
```

(There is a small performance penalty with (2) since the program has to compute all 3 evaluations.
I also changed `count()` to `size` which are equivalent)

Comment: I tried your method and it still gives the warning. The warning isn't for a specific line, it's the whole function.  Boolean method 'findError' is always inverted

Comment: can you provide the source / stub of `blocks` so I can compile...

Comment: The complete code is fairly extensive. Not sure how to add it all. Or do you just need a certain part?

Comment: In order to help you I/others might like to see the error directly from IntelliJ and play with the implementation to see what may be triggering it.  We cannot do this from the code snippet.  I think `blocks` is the only object we need the code for; just the fields

Comment: I added the stub block.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is IntelliJ trying to warn you that a boolean method result is *always* inverted after calling.  In other words, you *only* ever use `!findError()` in your code.

This is an indication that the code could be made more readable by using positive language.  JetBrain's [justification](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/09/the-inspection-connection-issue-2/) for this appears to be based on Robert Martin's book *Clean Code*:

> “Negatives are just a bit harder to understand than positives. So, when possible, conditionals should be expressed as positives.”

You can use `Refactor -> Invert Boolean...` to perform this automatically.

Comment: The Invert Boolean option is not available.  It is orange and not selectable. I've tried to rewrite it using positives but I can't get the same functionality.